# Best way to implement "zipLongest" in Scala

Tags: scala, collections, functional-programming

I need to implement a ["zipLongest"](https://docs.python.org/dev/library/itertools.html#itertools.zip_longest) function in Scala; that is, combine two sequences together as pairs, and if one is longer than the other, use a default value. (Unlike the standard `zip` method, which will just truncate to the shortest sequence.)

I've implemented it directly as follows:

```
def zipLongest[T](xs: Seq[T], ys: Seq[T], default: T): Seq[(T, T)] = (xs, ys) match {
  case (Seq(), Seq())           => Seq()
  case (Seq(), y +: rest)       => (default, y) +: zipLongest(Seq(), rest, default)
  case (x +: rest, Seq())       => (x, default) +: zipLongest(rest, Seq(), default)
  case (x +: restX, y +: restY) => (x, y) +: zipLongest(restX, restY, default)
}
```

Is there a better way to do it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use `zipAll` :

```
scala> val l1 = List(1,2,3)
l1: List[Int] = List(1, 2, 3)

scala> val l2 = List("a","b")
l2: List[String] = List(a, b)

scala> l1.zipAll(l2,0,".")
res0: List[(Int, String)] = List((1,a), (2,b), (3,.))
```

If you want to use the same default value for the first and second seq :

```
scala> def zipLongest[T](xs:Seq[T], ys:Seq[T], default:T) = xs.zipAll(ys, default, default)
zipLongest: [T](xs: Seq[T], ys: Seq[T], default: T)Seq[(T, T)]

scala> val l3 = List(4,5,6,7)
l3: List[Int] = List(4, 5, 6, 7)

scala> zipLongest(l1,l3,0)
res1: Seq[(Int, Int)] = List((1,4), (2,5), (3,6), (0,7))
```

Answer (score 6):

You can do this as a oneliner:

```
xs.padTo(ys.length, x).zip(ys.padTo(xs.length, y))
```